# Facebook Like Button to Facebook App (looks nice, but doesn't work right)

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-apps

I tried to add Like-plugin to Facebook App. I used Iframe-version. Plugin looks nice and seem to work, but when clicked it doesn't show any info of site in users wall or even photo. I guess problem is that Facebook can't scrape Facebook App URLs as Facebook URL Linter told me:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Is it possible to add proper Facebook Like to Facebook App? If yes, which URL should I use? apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx didn't work for me.

I really appreciate your knowledge and advice.

My iframe code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F347303448620703%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80&amp;appId=347303448620703" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do you mean "like" for facebook page/app ?

Comment: Yes, I mean "like" for Facebook App.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a like button code from here and add this code to your application  : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Yes, I know. But generated code doesn't work with Facebook Apps. I tried Iframe-version.

Comment: <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F347303448620703%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80&amp;appId=347303448620703" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

Comment: When i tried your application id for the like plugin and clicked on iFrame.  
It gave me this "This plugin does not have an iframe implementation with the selected options. Please use the JavaScript SDK and the HTML5 or XFBML implementations, or change the value of the send parameter."

Comment: Aby: I don't fully understand you. Send parameter is set to "false" as you see in the iframe code. That's not the problem I am facing. I guess  problem is that Facebook spider cannot index or scrape Facebook Apps, because those need authentication. Its kind of funny that you can't add Facebook Like-button to Facebook App. Don't understand me wrong, Facebook iframe Like-plugin is looking great, but working wrong. When user clicks "like" it should add photo and page title (my open graph tags are allright) to the post in users wall. Now it just posts link.

Comment: Got your issue.  The URL should be related to your facebook application page and not your application.  Thats why its not working.  

For Example :
App URL : http://apps.facebook.com/cityville/
Pages URL : http://www.facebook.com/pages/CityVille/168232079864416?ref=ts

Facebook Doesnt support like of App, they support like to page.